How would I apply Euler-Lagrange to this action?
I am trying to apply the Euler-Lagrange equations to the following action which is a type of $f(R)$ model:
$$S=\int\left(\sqrt{-g}\sqrt{ R^2 - \Lambda R + \Lambda^2} + T\right)dx^4$$
Where $R$ is the Ricci scalar and $\Lambda$ is the cosmological constant. I think I should get something approximating the usual Einstein equations with small corrections of order $\mathcal{O}(\Lambda)$. Any tips, or is there some software that could help me do this?
Is there perhaps a short cut to determine what kind of force law this gives? It should also be approximately $m_1 m_2/r^2$ at long distances.

Did you check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F(R)_gravity#Derivation_of_field_equations ?
